# connection string in with a local db c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection

I've created a database using Visual Studio 2015 by adding it locally as a mdf file

following this guide: [Walkthrough creating a local database SQL Server Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.100).aspx)

The exception that gets thrown is `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 81.`

I'm building a Windows Forms application.

My connection string looks like this `string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDb.mdf;Integrated";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user Visual Studio's server explorer to connect to your DB and then you'll get the correct connection string:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/

Comment: mate, you made my life soooo much easier!! I did not know that detail in VS thanky you very much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck.